# In how many ways can an examinee answer five questions, selecting at least one from each part?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**A question paper on mathematics consists of twelve questions divided into three parts A, B and C, each containing four questions. In how many ways can an examinee answer five questions, selecting at least one from each part?

(A) $624$ (B) $208$ (C) $1248$ (D) $2304$**

In the above question, the final answer is $624$, which I obtained from assuming every single possibility like selecting a single question from sets A and B and 3 from set C then multiplying whole of it by 3, and then assuming 1,2,2 questions from set A,B and C respectively and multiplying that with 3. When I tried it for the first time, I assumed that we can first select a single question from every set in $4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4$ ways and then we have to select 2 more questions, so we take $9C2$, i.e. selecting remaining 2 questions from the remaining 9 questions. By doing so, I get the answer as $2304$ which is wrong. I understood how taking individual assumptions gets the answer, but I'm not able to find my mistake in the wrong solution. Please explain the mistake in the solution.

Comment: A good way to self-diagnose is to consider a smaller version of the question: for example, what if there are four questions total, divide into two parts of two questions each, and you have to select three questions total?

Answer (score 1):

Your first time is counting the same cases multiple times.  You count cases with A1 and A2 twice, once when you select A1 as one of the first three and again when you select it as one of the last nine.  You count cases with A1, A2, and A3 three times for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it can be easily verified that (D) 2304 is incorrect, because even without any limit, the number of possible ways to choose 5 questions from the total 12 questions is ${12\choose 5}=792$ which is less than 2304, thus 2304 is impossible to be the right answer.

The problem of (D) 2304 is that a same set of selected questions with different orders (in each of A, B and C) are repeatedly counted. For instance, if the first 3 questions in A is selected, then $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$ is same as $(A_2,A_1,A_3)$, and they shouldn't be counted twice.

The right answer also can be obtained as ${12\choose 5}-{3\choose 1}*{8\choose 5}=624$.